# how could I get the content of a common class div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs 
one is both are containing one same class and all are in a div named "content" and may be the three div are comes random order.

```
<div class="error messages">Hello</div>
<div class="status messages">How</div>
<div class="error">are you</div>
```

So how could I get the text of "error messages" both class containing message in JS or jQuery?
I mean, I want to alert the "Hello" text, how can it be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both classes in the selector:

```
alert($('div.error.messages').text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rPw7F/

Comment: @SubhojitMukherjee np, feel free to accept it by clicking the tick over there <<<

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert( $('div.error.messsages').text() );
});
```